# Python math, Pythagora, degrees and coordinates

Tags: python, math, coordinates, degrees, pythagorean

Is me again. Did I mention how much I love you guys? My prof talked me into trying python, so far I hate it, but I decided to give it a try. I have made a simple program, using pygame, that moves few circles around the screen. I have issues with some math problems in it. I gave each circle (x, y) coordinates (the center of circle) and I calculated their shifts(Dx, Dy) on the screen, based on the speed (distance per move) I want them to move.
This is what I have done for the move method:

```
def Move(self, speed):
    Dx = self.qx * (speed * math.sin(math.degrees(90 - Alp)))
    Dy = self.qy * (speed * math.sin(math.degrees(Alp)))
    self.x += Dx
    self.y += Dy
    print "D = ", math.sqrt(Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy)
```

the problem:
I calculate Dx and Dy based on speed using Pythagorahs theorem, and then, calculating D (actaully speed) in print statement using the same theorem, I should Have a result equal to speed that is inputed. But, the result I get is:

```
    D =  9.15180313227 (speed  = 10)
```

The result varies and is not always the same (I have test method with random values), but it's always close and wrong. What am I missing?

NOTE: Ignore self.qy and self.qx, they are used to properly determine the direction, their value is either 1 or -1

Comment: Dono if this would solve the problem. But you should use `math.radians` to convert from degrees to radians. `math.sin` expects the angle to be in radians.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but note there's also a `math.hypot()` function.

Comment: @M4rtini, that was the problem, thank yoiu for answering as well :) martineau, I'm not sure where you wanted to go with this?

Comment: Instead of using `math.sin(math.radians(90 - Alp))` you can as well use the more readable `math.cos(math.radians(Alp))`.

Comment: @Lutzl Thank you, it did not occur to me at that time, that this is the same, I was too focused on basic problem to see this :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking to your code, and precisely where you call `math.degrees(90-Alp)`, it seems to me that you understood `math.degrees` in the wrong way:

```
>>> math.degrees(2)
114.59 (...)
```

This function converts *radians* to *degrees*, not the opposite. How does it perform if you use `math.radians` instead?